# Function that strips trailing '0's from a float

Tags: algorithm, c, formatting, floating-point, embedded

I'm writing an embedded application in C, and at one point I need to convert a float into an ASCII representation of that float, so I can send the ASCII over a serial port. The protocol the serial port is listening over doesn't like trailing 
'0's, so I'm writing a function that will remove all of the unnecessary '0's at the end of the ASCII string. Here is what my expected inputs and outputs look like:

```
#input           #output
300.000      --> 300.
300.01400    --> 300.014
300.1200     --> 300.12
300.12345678 --> 300.12345   #Only 5 decimal places of precision
```

Here is the function:

```
int float_to_str(float f, char *output, int buffer_size)
{
    int buf_len = snprintf(output, buffer_size, "%0.5f", f);

    //Strip trailing '0's from response
    bool seen_point = false;
    int real_len = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < buf_len && index < buffer_size)
    {
        if (output[index] == '.')
            seen_point = true;
        if (output[index] != '0' || !seen_point)
            real_len = index + 1;
        index++;
    }

    return real_len;
}
```

The return value is the length of the string stuffed into `output`, which will never be more than `buffer_size`.

Is this well written and easy to understand? Am I overlooking edge-cases? How about the choice of algorithm, is there a simpler way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Are you okay with leaving the `.` alone at the end when all zeros are removed?

Comment: @glampert Yes, that is desired. The program that listens to the board watches for a `.` in the number to tell if it's a float or an int.

Comment: Question: for your last input example, you say `300.123456789` should yield `300.12345`. Does that mean you don't want the nearest rounded 5-digit precision value (which would be `300.12346`)? Do you mean to truncate, or do you want the number rounded?

Comment: Typical `float x = 300.123456789;` will result in a value of `300.123443...` and that value printed with `"%.5f"` becomes `"300.12344"`, not the `300.12345` posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts are as follows:

1. Since you are leveraging `snprintf`, you have already limited the string size to `buffer_size`, so the additional condition in the `while` loop should not be needed.
2. Since there is no validation, I'm assuming the data has been validated before and that the value will never exceed `buffer_size` with, which allows for the following simplification:

   ```
   int float_to_str(float f, char *output, int buffer_size)
   {
       int buf_len = snprintf(output, buffer_size, "%0.5f", f);
       if(buf_len>buffer_size) return -1 ; // updated to add validation
       //Strip trailing '0's from response
       while (buf_len>0)
       {
           if (output[buf_len-1] == '0') // is the last char a zero?
           {
               output[buf_len-1]=0;  // null terminate the string
               buf_len--;  
           }
           else break;  // if this is not a zero, we are either at the . or a non zero digit
       }
       return buf_len;  
   }
   ```
3. I'm not sure your code will return the correct result if the input is 300.00014, my initial thought is your output would be 300.00.

Comment: `snprintf` returns the length the float would take up if unlimited by the buffer, see e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/), so your code is likely to produce some nasty segfaults).

Comment: I should point out that your code starts at the front and iterates through the string.  The code I posted starts at the end of the string and walks backwards till it finds a non zero.  It would never exceed 5 iterations of the loop unless there is no . in the string.

Comment: I updated my last comment, the code should have validation added.  Return error code if buf_len is larger then buffer_size because we no longer have a valid value to work with.  Add the following right after the snprinf line:   if(buf_len>buffer_size) return -1;

Comment: You can edit your answer to include those changes. Also, this won't compile as `real_len` is never declared.

Comment: Off by 1. Suggest `if(buf_len>buffer_size) return -1 ;` --> `if(buf_len>=buffer_size) return -1 ;`  > vs. >=  "... the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than n." C11 §7.21.6.5 3

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Horn](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/126047/29485) fine 1st time answer: Minor stuff:

Use `size_t` rather than `int` for array sizes as it is 1) the best type for array indexing 2) the type expected by `snprintf()`.

```
// int float_to_str(float f, char *output, int buffer_size) {
int float_to_str(float f, char *output, size_t buffer_size) {
  int buf_len = snprintf(output, buffer_size, "%0.5f", f);
```

Pedantic code would check `buf_len` for insufficient buffer size and encoding errors

```
  if (buf_len < 0 || buf_len >= buffer_size) return -1; // error
```

Questionable if `300.12345678` --> `"300.12345"` is realistic as typical `float` lacks that much precision and will render `"300.12344"` instead.

Note that `float f = 300.014;` will typically result in `"300.01401"` for similar reasons.

---

"protocol ... doesn't like trailing '0's" is suspicious.  Detailing the protocol needs may result in a better answer for the higher level problem.